Doctrine ODM: create DocumentManagers dynamically
Our app is using Symfony with Doctrine ODM. We have multiple databases (one per customer) in MongoDB, that all use the same schema.
Currently, we select the database by setting the default db on the default DocumentManager, as suggested by this answer.
Since we experience issues when working with documents from different databases during the same request, we would like to use one DocumentManager per database instead.
As we don't know which databases exist or which we're going to use in this request, we cannot define the DocumentManagers statically in doctrine_mongodb.yaml.
We already tried to create them with DocumentManager::create() in the controller, but this approach comes to its limits in combination with Dependency Injection: Other services still use the default DocumentManager from the DI Container.
How can we make sure that all services use the appropriate DocumentManager that is created dynamically during request processing?
Are there any design patterns that support this kind of service architecture?

Years back I did this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42142666/5982920) and still think it was the best approach

Thank you @malarzm! That's similar to what I tried with DocumentManager::create() in the controller. Unfortunately I cannot see how that solves the issue with Dependency Injection - the DocumentManagerFactory is not the only service that expects a DocumentManager as a constructor parameter. How can I make Symfony inject the instances that are created by the factory into other services? I know this, but I cannot pass the Context from services.yaml, as it is created in the controller.

Back then we ended up injecting a DocumentManagerFactory in places that'd normally have a DocumentManager injected and pass Context down from controllers (or have it accessible through a service, and context itself created before controllers come into play). This allows you to be explicit what you're doing.

Yes, maybe I'll do that... But it's only possible if we have control over the code of services that need a DocumentManager. Still wondering if it's possible without touching all the service implementations.

Well you said yourself you need to use multiple databases in same request. How would Symfony know which DM to use if there's no context to be determined (or passed as you don't want to modify implementations)?

In my idea, the services are not aware of the context. Only the controller is aware of the context. When the context changes, all services that depend on a DocumentManager will have to be re-created. Thinking in terms of "duplicate the DI container and rebuild it with a different DocumentManager".
